# sqlite fetching data using foreign key: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to fetch a record from the sqlite database in Android, and having trouble. It often throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException and gives me the same message.

```
 mListSongs = mSongDao.getSelectedSongs(artist_id);



public List<Song> getSelectedSongs(Long artistId) {
    List<Song> listSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SONG_PATH + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SONG + " s, "
            + DBHelper.TABLE_ARTIST + " a WHERE s."
            + DBHelper.SONG_ID + " = a.'" + DBHelper.ARTIST_ID + "'";               
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(artistId)};
    Cursor cursor;

    cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, selectionArgs);



    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Song song = cursorToSelectSong(cursor);
        listSongs.add(song);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return listSongs;
}
private Song cursorToSelectSong(Cursor cursor) {Song song = new Song(); song.setmSong_path(cursor.getString(3)); return song;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are supplying an argument, as per `String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(artistId)};` and then `cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, selectionArgs);` but that the statement (the SELECT statement) has no place-holder (an **?**) within it.

So you have **1 argument** but the statement has **0 parameters** to substitute the argument for.

Changing :-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SONG_PATH + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SONG + " s, "
        + DBHelper.TABLE_ARTIST + " a WHERE s."
        + DBHelper.SONG_ID + " = a.'" + DBHelper.ARTIST_ID + "'";
```

to :-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SONG_PATH + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SONG + " s, "
        + DBHelper.TABLE_ARTIST + " a WHERE s."
        + DBHelper.SONG_ID + "=?";
```

Introduces the parameter and it, the **?**, will be substituted for the **artist_id** passed to the method.

Alternately using :-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SONG_PATH + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SONG + " s, "
    + DBHelper.TABLE_ARTIST + " a WHERE s."
    + DBHelper.SONG_ID + " =" + String.valueOf(artist_id);
```

along with :-

```
cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

would also work BUT is open to SQL injection (but not really as it's a long that has been passed, which cannot be a String that could contain dangerous SQL).

- i.e. no arguments are passed into rawQuery and therefore there is no expectation that the statement should contain a parameter place-holder (**?**).

However, there is no need to **JOIN** the **ARTIST** table as the **SONG** table has the **ARTIST_ID** column.

- *You'd only need the JOIN if you wanted other details about the ARTIST e.g. artist name (which you probably already know as you've ascertained the ARTIST_ID when invoking the method)*.

As such the simplified :-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SONG_PATH + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + DBHelper.SONG_ID + "=?";
```

would suffice.

Regarding Cursor issues I'd suggest trying :-

```
cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, selectionArgs);
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor); //<<<<<<<<<< will output the contents of the cursor to the log
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String songpath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SONG_PATH));
    Log.d("EXTRACTEDPATH", "Extracted PATH " + songpath); //<<<<<<<<<< output extracted path to the log
    Song newsong = new Song();
    newsong.setmSong_path(songpath);
    listSongs.add(newsong);
}
cursor.close();
return listSongs;
```

}

- Dumps the Cursor immediately after it is retrieved
- Uses simpler loop
- Uses column name to derive the column offset
- outputs the data from the column (if it shows path in log, but you still get empty path in list then it's either setmSong_path that is wrong or how you are getting data from the List.)

Comment: This is not just answer to my question it is life saving answer for me. now i'm stuck here my it is returning empty string.     Song song = new Song();
        song.setmSong_name(cursor.getString(0));
        return song;

Comment: here is the link of this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541336/if-my-table-has-4-colums-and-i-want-to-fetch-the-3rd-column-what-do-i-do]

Comment: perhaps the path is in fact empty. Try using `String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + DBHelper.SONG_ID + "=?";` and then check to see if other values exist. If not then please ask a new question (1:30 in the morning here, have to get up in 4 hours so need some sleep)

Comment: nope path is not empty. i have another activity that shows all the value in song table. and path is shown on that activity.

Comment: @AliRaza Instead of `cursor.getString(0)` (only 1 column so must be 0 not 3) use `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SONG_PATH));`. Also you may wish to try adding `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);` immediately after the line `cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, selectionArgs);` it will output the contents of the Cursor to the log.

Comment: @AliRaza edited the answer, but not sure it will resolve the issue (P.S. code isn't tested, just written say may have some typos). Also answered other question re column offset (and why not to use them).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184494/discussion-between-miket-and-ali-raza).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to fetch a list of songs by an artist, providing the `artistId`.
I believe that in in each row of the songs table `DBHelper.TABLE_SONG` there is a column for the id of the artist. If there isn't **it should be**. 
Change your sql statement to this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SONG_PATH + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + DBHelper.ARTIST_ID + " = ?";
```

As I said there must be a column `DBHelper.ARTIST_ID` or similar to identify the artist of each song.
The `?` is the 1 parameter and its value will be `artistId`.